# Drupal 6 - Captcha 6.24 - Cron fails to truncate captcha_sessions table

Tags: drupal, cron, captcha

Environment:

Drupal 6
Captcha 6.24

**Problem**

Today the module started giving problems. The first clue as to what was happening was through **Reports > Recent log entries** . It was plagued with the following:

```
Duplicate entry ***** for key ******  query: 
INSERT into captcha_sessions (uid, sid, ip_address, timestamp, 
form_id, solution, status, attempts) VALUES (....)
```

As expected, the table was HUGE, I'm talking over 25mbs. I was under the impression that Drupal´s cron was in charge of deleting the data in this table (as well as logs) when it ran. Since it's Drupal 6 I went over to **poormanscron** and had it run....but nothing changed.

My temporary solution was to truncate, manually, said table. But it bugs me that Drupal´s cron is not doing so on its own. So, I'm left wondering, is my only chance to keep this table at low size with a custom script server side?

Is there something I need to set so that Drupal's cron deletes logs and clears that table? Since it's Drupal 6 I'm a listtle lost, because in Drupal 7 I could just create a cron job.

Thank in advance.

**Edit**

This function is found in the `captcha.module` file. But it's not doing as it says, the table never gets truncated.

```
function catpcha_cron{
   db_query('DELETE FROM {captcha_sessions} WHERE timestamp < %d', time() - 60*60*24);
}
```

Comment: Check the log for errors... `captcha_cron()` "remove challenges older than 1 day" so if your cron is running either that should be happening or you should at least see an error

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I've gone to Recent log entries, in there I've filtered by cron. And all I see are 4 entries with Cron run completed...and by a Non-Member on top of that. What I will do is create that captcha_cron() function in the module or see if it's in there in the first place and carry out my table truncation in there.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I needed the challenges older than a timestamp to be truncated rather than older than a day since the table gets quicly filled up and I don't have much space to spare. All I did was change the function in the module in charge of said truncation **captcha.module**.

```
function catpcha_cron{
   db_query('DELETE FROM {captcha_sessions} WHERE timestamp < %d', time());
}
```

ps: I upvoted @Clive's comment since it led me in the right path. Thanks!